# Angular excel file upload throws NotOfficeXmlFileException

Tags: java, angular, excel, rest

i want to upload a excel file with Angular and send it via REST API to the backend. The file is create in MS Excel as an .xlsx file. But when i try to read the excel file i got the following exception at the backend service:

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:156)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:94)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:132)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:312)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:289)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:285)
    at 
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Unexpected record signature: 0X2D2D2D2D
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveInputStream.getNextZipEntry(ZipArchiveInputStream.java:296)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipArchiveThresholdInputStream.java:152)
    ... 86 more
```

Here the Angular Rest call:

```
     onFileSelect(event): void {
        const file: File = event.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("file", file);

            this.http.post('/rest/upload', formData)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let body = response.json();
                return body || [];
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => {
                return this.handleError(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

And here the backend code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<BaselineJson>> uploadExcel(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream excelFile) {
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        ....
```

Any help?

Comment: Is it possible to write a java unit test, using the actual file, before using the angular layer?  Or even a main method, if you don't want to go to the trouble of writing a method. Unless you've already done that of course.

Comment: @PeterS JUnit runs ok without exception. Could be the serialization of the file cause the error?

Comment: Yes almost certainly. I would look into using http.request as a call and not the post.

Comment: You also seem to be missing mime content headers, so I'm assuming it will go into JSON mode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try the following headers in your call:

```
this.http.post('/rest/upload', formData)....
```

The headers seem to work depending on some environments/browsers, however remove them for now.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadExcel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile excelFile) {
```

And then create a workbook like so:

```
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile.getInputStream());
```

Can you check this for me?

People wishing to check the full demo answer, can check the github entry here:

[github.com/inthegarage/file-uploader](https://github.com/inthegarage/file-uploader)

Comment: Unfortunatly not, same error. The payload of the request looks like:

-----------------------------66994835534695100932634337947
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="baselines.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

PK ....

The header contains: Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Comment: @MathiasNoack Please check my latest edit, the method signature, did not work for me, but using MultipartFile, worked 100%. This is in spring 5, can you use that? you didn't say.

Comment: Get the following error with spring-web-4.3.11: Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2856)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2824)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359)

Comment: @MathiasNoack please try removing the headers, I've updated my example, that may work.

Comment: i removed the headers. Still get the error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Comment: @MathiasNoack I will provide my set-up for you to check. I'll place it over on git later today.

Comment: @MathiasNoack Please check the project here: https://github.com/inthegarage/file-uploader

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try and give you feedback later.

Comment: Your example is running and works without errors. Now i have to check my projects settings to find the problem. Thanks for your help @PeterS

Comment: @MathiasNoack Good news, your issue will probably be mime type, maybe a browser issue as well. I tested on latest Chrome & Firefox. Check that isn't causing an issue. Hope you get it working.